# Show Product Meta Keywords in Product pages

Tags: products, meta-tags, tags, meta, meta-keywords

Is there a way to show all meta keywords for a product on its product detail page. something looks like below? [image]

I'm currently able to display the meta-keyword attribute values under the email icon( I added the following code at the end of the mailto.phtml).

```
<div class="tags">
    <hr />
        <b><?php echo $_product->getData('meta_keyword'); ?></b>
</div>
```

However, I want to display them like the image above ( in individual box) and move them underneath product title.
[image]

Comment: what you have tried. How you have managed `Meta Keywork`

Comment: i'm currently able to display the meta keywords underneath the email icon ( i added it at the end of the mailto.phtml). my Meta Keywords are store in the product attributes called 'meta_keyword'. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reach this by creating `catalog_product_view.xml` layout in your custom module and add your block into `product.info.main` container like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="meta_keywords" template="Test_Module::meta_keywords.phtml" before="-" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

meta_keywords.phtml template:

```
<?php /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View $block */ ?>

<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getProduct()->getData('meta_keywords')) ?>
```

Comment: thank you, it get me into the right direction.